# How a webview can fill all the page?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developping a blackberry 10 mobile application using the momentics IDE (native sdk).

I'm trying to put in a qml page a webview that its display should take the hole parent 
container  dimensions (width and height) like mentioned in the code below . But for a reason that I didin't find, it doesn't. Anyone have an idea on this ?

```
    Page {
        content: Container {
            id: mainEntryContainer
            objectName: "mainEntryContObj"

            layout: StackLayout {
                orientation: LayoutOrientation.TopToBottom
            }

            background: Color.create("#292929")

            FastBarHeader {
                id: headerContainer
                objectName: "headerContObj"
            }

            Container {
                id: choosedOptionContainer
                objectName: "choosedOptionContObj"

                layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
                    spaceQuota: 8
                }

                WebView {
                   id: htmlViewerItem
                   objectName: "htmlViewerItemObj"

                   horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                   verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill

                   settings.cookiesEnabled: true
                   settings.javaScriptEnabled: true

                   settings.devicePixelRatio: 1.0
                   settings.viewport: {
                         "initial-scale": 1.0
                    }

                    onLoadingChanged: {
                      if (loadRequest.status == WebLoadStatus.Succeeded) {
                           indicatorProgress.progIndicatorLabelValue = "Load finished."
                           visible = true
                           indicatorProgress.visible = false
                      } else if (loadRequest.status == WebLoadStatus.Failed) {
                           indicatorProgress.progIndicatorLabelValue = "Load failed."
                      }

                     }

                   accessibility.name: "web content"
                }
            }

            FastBarFooter {
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the spacequota?

Comment: YES !! I need it to divide the page into 3 parts and make sure no one would take the space of another part. Actualy, it only happen when it's a webview; I tried to put other qml components in place of the webview and it works perfectly . Really strange !!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you'll need to wrap the WebView inside of a ScrollView (this allows the webview to scroll properly if needed).

Here's how I accomplish this:

```
ScrollView {
    id: scrollview

    implicitLayoutAnimationsEnabled: false
    scrollViewProperties.minContentScale: 1.0

    WebView {
        id: webview
        preferredHeight: Infinity
        preferredWidth: Infinity

        // viewport setup
        settings.viewport: {
            "width": "device-width",
            "height": "device-height",
            "initial-scale": 1.0
        }
    } // WebView

} // ScrollView
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the containers with and height the WebViews preferred size with this in the parent container:

```
attachedObjects: LayoutUpdateHandler {
        onLayoutFrameChanged: {
            <your_webview_id>.preferredWidth = layoutFrame.width;
            <your_webview_id>.preferredHeight = layoutFrame.height;
        }
    }
```